# Accidentally changed permissions of /usr/bin, how do I fix?

Tags: mac

I have a Mac and I accidentally ran

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/bin
```

I just realized I screwed up, it had to do with some stupid npm permissions! (Npm errors drive me crazy sometimes and I was looking for a quick fix)

I managed to get `sudo` working by following [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1248734) to [sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set [OSX]](https://superuser.com/questions/1248720/sudo-usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set-osx)

How do I fix `/usr/bin` back to the original permissions? Should I just backup and do a system reinstall?

Comment: SIP shouldn't have let you do that - https://superuser.com/questions/1049689/which-folders-are-affected-by-system-integrity-protection

Comment: @dsstorefile1 - That hasn't been in Disk Utils since Mavericks. You have to do it the hard way now - `diskutil resetUserPermissions / \`id -u\``

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything in /usr/bin is owned by root, and assigned to the wheel group. It's easiest to set everything to that, then correct the few exceptions:

```
sudo chmod root:wheel /usr/bin/*
sudo chmod _uucp /usr/bin/{cu,uucp,uuname,uustat,uux}
sudo chgrp tty /usr/bin/write
```

That should be correct for macOS High Sierra (v10.13) and Mojave (v10.14); I'm not sure about Sierra (v10.12), but in El Capitan (v10.11) /usr/bin/wall should also be assigned to the tty group.

Of course, you have to have System Integrity Protection turned off to do this; but I assume it's already off or it would've prevented the original change.